# if window width is bigger than 800px remove this div, but without refreshing site

Tags: jquery

I'm having this problem I have in jquery that when window width is bigger than 800px remove this div:

```
if ($(window).width() > 800) {
  $('.menu').remove();
}
```

But it doesn't happen instantly, you have to refresh site when window width is bigger than 800px. Btw. I have some CSS attached to `.menu`. I heard something about event `preventDefault()`, but it works with links or something like that. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Consider using a CSS media query for that instead of jQuery.

Comment: downvote war between answers LOL.

Comment: @Mr.ZZ No, it wasn't, as I didn't downvote anything here

Comment: @Mr.ZZ no, it's not. I've never downvoted an answer, and included the jQuery with attribute to LGSon, so why would I downvote an answer that I referenced? But some people downvote all answers if they don't like the question (perhaps because MikeMcCaughan marked it as a duplicate).

Comment: @LGSon Why did you delete your answer? It was the direct answer to the question. Mine is more a recommendation for an alternative solution.

Comment: I saw edit war and then downvote war xD.

Comment: @RacilHilan Your answer had the same solution mine had, and no point having 2.

Comment: @Mr.ZZ Not everything that shine is gold :). I don't know about LGSon, but yes I edited my answer a few times. This is something I often do because you have a 5 minutes window to edit your answer without counting it as an edit. So nothing special here and certainly not a voting war. Somebody downvoted all of us (the question and answers).

Comment: @LGSon  I didn't mean for my answer to have the same solution, which is why I referenced yours. I only needed it to say the last sentence, the reason why I recommended a media query. Now it is referencing a deleted answer :(.

Comment: Btw. thank you guys for your answers :D

Comment: @RacilHilan We likely wrote it at the same time...and now I fixed the reference issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a CSS media query for that instead of jQuery:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .menu { display: none; }
}
```

If you want to use jQuery (or JavaScript), you need to place that code in the `resize` event handler:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 800) {
    $('.menu').remove();
  }
});
```

The `resize` event doesn't work smoothly on some browsers especially the mobile browsers.